# Modified paste function in R tutorial (Swirl)

Tags: r, swirl

Trying to create a modified version of paste function where any input text needs to be bracketed by "stop" and "start". Failing code is:

```
telegram.paste <- function(...) {paste("START", "...", "STOP")}
```

As a fairly new user I'm struggling to identify the issue with my code and either an explanation or link to one would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Loose the quotes around `...`: try `telegram.paste <- function(...) {paste("START",..., "STOP")}`

Answer (score 3):

You are using the ellipsis `...`. If you want to pass these arguments to  `paste` you have to remove the `" "`.
So

```
telegram.paste <- function(...) {paste("START", ..., "STOP")}
```

will work.

```
telegram.paste("This is a telegram")
# [1] "START This is a telegram STOP"
telegram.paste("This", "will", "work", "also")
# [1] "START This will work also STOP"
```